# Numpy sort array by a single row:

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

Let's say I have array:

```
a = np.array([[9, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

I want output:

```
[[2, 3, 9],
 [2, 3, 1]]
```

Basically, I want to sort the first row and I want the rest of the rows to follow their sorted counterparts

Answer (score 2):

You could try subscripting `a` on columns using sort positions of the first row:

```
a = a[:,a[0].argsort()]
```

Comment: You're a saint!